# Is this proof of Bernoulli’s inequality correct?

Tags: solution-verification

I have to prove $(1+x)^{n} >1+nx$ for $n=2,3,4.... $and $x>-1$ and $x$ isnt 0. There are a lot of proofs of this but l want to know if this one works. If not, can u show where my reasoning is weak.

If $x>-1$ then $1+x>0$
Hence $ (1+x)^{n}>0$ for $n>=2$ and $x>-1$ . For $1+nx$ . I can show that $1+nx=0$ for $n=2,x=-.5$

Since $nx+1>0$ isn't true for a single pair (n,x) in the list of all pairs, the statement that it is true for all pairs of (n,x) is also false.

So $(1+x)^{n}>1+nx$ for $n=2,3,4.... $and $x>-1$.

Comment: How does the last line follow? What if $x>0$?

Comment: @chrystomath.  $ (1+x)^{n}>0$ for all n>=2 but 1+nx<0 for a single pair ,then it can't be true for all pairs . We don't need to verify further on. That's how l am reasoning, can u explain how this reasoning produces false results.

Comment: Looks like a complete *non sequitur* to me. Can you at least prove that $(1+x)^2\ge1+2x$?

Comment: @angina sure 1+2x+x^2 >=1+2x, equal when x=0. Wait x cant be zero in bernoulli inequality. : )

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand where your conclusion came from. Could you maybe edit the question to explain in a little more details for us?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I give a counter example to the statement nx+1>0 for n>=2 and x>-1, where x isn't zero.  A single counter example should suffice to prove it wrong. Since l have proved that$ (1+x)^{n}>0$ for the conditions,$ (1+x)^{n}$> nx+1.

Comment: Why would a single counterexample work? Proving there exists a ${(n,x)}$ pair such that ${1 + nx\leq0}$ **does not prove for every ${(n,x)}$ pair** that ${(1+x)^n>1+nx}$. How do you know there isn't some ${(n,x)}$ pair such that ${1+nx>0}$ and ${(1+x)^n > 1+nx}$?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I think l sort of get your point. If $1+nx>0$ , we cannot say anything about its relation to $(1+x)^{n}$ . So if l prove $1+nx<0 $ for a certain $(n,x)$ , l cannot claim that it is less than $(1+x)^{n}$ for all $(n,x)$ . Correct or not ?

Comment: Correct. You can see my answer for an analogy and also another method of proof

Comment: One last thing to note - it should be ${\geq}$, not ${>}$. If ${x=0}$, both sides are equal to eachother. It was probably a typo but I thought I'd just point it out incase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your proof is not valid, since we are not trying to disprove anything - so a counterexample approach won't work. "It's not true for a single pair, so it's not true for all pairs" is the incorrect reasoning. That's like saying "every car I've seen today has been red, so every car is red". It doesn't work.

Instead, you could prove the statement by induction. Take arbitrary ${x>-1}$ and ${n \in \{2,3,4,5,6...\}}$. Then for ${n=2}$, the statement is clear

$${(1+x)^2 = 1 + 2x + x^2 \geq 1 + 2x}$$

(since ${x^2\geq 0}$ for any ${x}$). Hence the statement ${(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx}$ is true for ${n=2}$. Now assume that for some ${n=k}$ where ${k \in \{2,3,4,...\}}$ that

$${(1+x)^k \geq 1+kx}$$

Then notice

$${(1+x)^{k+1}=(1+x)(1+x)^k\geq (1+x)(1+kx)=1+kx+x+kx^2 = 1+(k+1)x + kx^2}$$

And again since ${kx^2}$ will be ${\geq 0}$ we have

$${1+(k+1)x + kx^2 \geq 1+(k+1)x}$$

So

$${(1+x)^{k+1}\geq 1+(k+1)x}$$

Since we have shown that the statement is true for ${n=k+1}$ if it's true for ${n=k}$, and we have shown it's true for ${n=2}$ we have the statement is true also for ${n=3,4,5....}$ and so by the Principle of Mathematical Induction we now have that

$${(1+x)^{n}\geq 1+nx}$$

for ${n \in \{2,3,4,5,6,...\}}$ and ${x>-1}$, as required.